# How might I rewrite this function so that it supports a keyword argument while preserving what case-lambda does for the other arguments?

Tags: function, scheme, racket

I've read that `case-lambda` [does not directly support keyword arguments](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/lambda.html#%28form._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._case-lambda%29%29).
How might I rewrite the code below so that the function `greet-weightlifter` supports
keyword arguments.

```
(define greet-weightlifter 
  (case-lambda ((nombre nombre-segundo) (string-append "Hola, " nombre " " nombre-segundo "."))
               ((name) (string-append "Hi, " name "."))
               ;((#:pref p) (string-append "Hi, would you do a " p " for me, my gentle athlete?")); this does not work
                             ))

(greet-weightlifter "Vanessa" "Lizárraga")
(greet-weightlifter "Busra")
;(greet-weightlifter #:pref"squat")
```

The lines that are commented out do not work. I need to rewrite `greet-weightlifter`
in such a way so that the call `(greet-weightlifter #:pref"squat")` would work.
How might I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`case-lambda` might not support keywords, but [pattern matching](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/match.html), in this case in the form of [`define/match`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/match.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fmatch..rkt%29._define%2Fmatch%29%29) does. Combine that with a default value for the argument and putting any other arguments in a rest list, and:

```lisp
#lang racket/base
(require racket/match)

(define/match (greet-weightlifter #:pref [move #f] . rst)
  [(#f (list name)) #:when (string? name)
                    (string-append "Hi, " name ".")]
  [(#f (list nombre nombre-segundo)) #:when (and (string? nombre)
                                                 (string? nombre-segundo))
                                     (string-append "Hola, " nombre " " nombre-segundo ".")]
  [(p '()) #:when (string? p)
           (string-append "Hi, would you do a " p " for me, my gentle athlete?")])


(displayln (greet-weightlifter "Vanessa" "Lizárraga"))
(displayln (greet-weightlifter "Busra"))
(displayln (greet-weightlifter #:pref "squat"))
```

Trying to use other arguments than these three cases, or with values that aren't strings, raises a runtime exception.